# Как изменить текст в DIV contenteditable?

Tags: jquery

Второй день уже мучаюсь, не знаю как изменить текст в таком div.
Я хочу чтобы текст менялся при вводе, например ввели любой текст или букву и тут же сразу в div появлялся текст который прописан в JS.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="data" type="text></div>
```

Пробовал так но не получается ничего.

```
$('#data').keydown(function(e) {

    $('#data').text("Мой текст");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.block');

function changeText() {
  this.textContent = 'My text';
}

block.addEventListener("keyup", changeText);
```

```css
.block{
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="block">Text</div>
```

Comment: Ты хорошо разбираешься в JQ ? Есть предложение.

Comment: Питаюсь сделать так чтобы если в contenteditable есть ссылка то сделать ее активной, взять ее в тег a уже второй день мучаюсь, я уже на кофе готов кинуть если поможешь.

Comment: Приблизительно так - https://jsfiddle.net/5m89260v/

Comment: Когда ввожу адрес, например http://goog.ru он так и остается текстовым а нужно чтобы стал активным. Я вот вопрос со своим примером задавал - https://cutt.ly/dr8pNiS